# How do Busniess Rules fit into or with the Entity Framework generated Entites?

Tags: entity-framework

Let's say I am using a traditional 3-layer application (UI-BLL-DAL) in a .NET application, where would the busniess rules be applied in reference to the generated Entity class? Would you extend the entity with a partial class and add the rules there, pass the Entity up to the BLL map to a busniess object and process rules in a separate class, or something entirely different? What has been the common practice thus far?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put business logic in your entities. Entities exist to map the DB interface to the application and, hence, [aren't really even objects](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/31/AtTheBoundariesApplicationsAreNotObjectOriented.aspx).

Also, putting business logic in your entities makes them fat and confusing. You'll have some properties which exist for DB mapping. Others which represent runtime concerns. Some methods you can call in an L2E query. Some you can't. It's a mess. Also, it makes your business logic deeply tied up in EF code, which is a bad separation of concerns.

We write services for business processes. Each service is constructor-injected with repositories for the data it needs. The business logic is *totally separate* from the EF mapping concern. It might not even use EF types. For example, you can write code like:

```
var q = from l in Context.Animals.OfType<Lemur>()
        select new LemurDto
        {
            Id = l.Id,
            IsKing = l.Name.Equals("Julien XIII")
        };
var service = new LemurCountService(q);
return service.Inventory();
```

So in this case the `LemurCountService` is totally independent of the EF.

Comment: Nice, so in your case the service that is injected with the Repository is preforming the business rules correct? Also for something like data binding: would your business objects map to certain properties from the Entity and then in turn be bound to, or would you bind directly to the Entity?

Comment: That's right regarding services. No, I don't bind to entities; [I bind to presentation models](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/12/31/38500/).

Comment: Perfect, perfect, perfect! That is exactly what I was looking for. Quite Similar to creating Presentation Views mapped from Domain objects in the Application Services layer in DDD. Nice post by the way, and thanks for your help.